# 'BadDeviceToken' APN errors for en_VN (Vietnam)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10, ios11

After releasing our latest version of our app built for iOS 11 using Xcode 9 the day iOS 11 came out (Sept 19th), we are seeing an increase in 'BadDeviceToken' errors from APN service and we have specifically narrowed them down as originating in the locale en_VN (Vietnam).

Interestingly, these errors came from devices running iOS 10 or iOS 9 through a wide range of device types.

We are registering for push notifications in our iOS app using registerForRemoteNotifications() - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications

Any suggestions on what might be leading to bad tokens only in one specific country?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use an APNS provider? Are you sure that the environment used is correct (production vs. sandbox)?

Comment: @B7 I should have mentioned that we send these directly to apple's push notification service (through aws), as we handle the backend to sending pushes as well as subscriptions ourselves. Interestingly the 'BadDeviceToken' error responses are only coming from pushes sent to Vietnam region, but all other countries are successful. This is production.

Comment: Wondering if there may be a firewall in Vietnam blocking Apple requests and if that could lead to a case like this. We can track all other analytics requests from those devices with those tokens, and they are definitely real users browsing our app.

Comment: Did you try to regenerate the tokens before sending the notification?

Comment: @ruxy have you solved your issue ? for vitnam country

Comment: @dipali it resolved itself... may have been something on the Apple side.